# Interfacing PHP with an Excel spreadsheet / VBA Script

Tags: php, html, excel, vba

I have a client that has developed an Excel spreadsheet to calculate various statistics using VBA Script (Excel/VBA is not my forte to say the least). He wants me to create a web front-end for this (I will be using PHP / CakePHP) that will have a simple form for inputting cell values, will query the spreadsheet and return the values for display on the website.

The client does not want to convert the Excel/VBA script to another language - he wants to keep it in a 'silo' and just have the website query the existing script.

Is this possible? Any libraries that can help? How could I go about this?

Comment: So you want a web page to take values as input .. then the PHP script to open an Excel spreadsheet, input the values, read a cell and output that value to the browser ... (just to clarify)

Comment: Yes I think that would do it... Am I right in thinking that I can't use a library such as PHPExcel to do this? Would I need to run the Excel application on a virtual server or something similar? Or am I overcomplicating?

Comment: You're right - even PHPExcel can't run VBAScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to run MS Excel itself, and use COM... it's the only method of which I'm aware that would allow you to run VBAScript within the Excel workbook from your PHP. You couldn't even use OpenOffice for this, so it limits you to a Windows Server with MS Excel installed